# NMAP shows all filtered ports in GCP with Kubernetes/Docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, nmap

I have a tool that uses `nmap` to run a basic port scan on a host to check for open ports. It's setup in a docker container and on my local machine, works perfectly (shows the expected ports being open, etc.).

When I deploy this container to a Kubernetes cluster in Google Cloud and trigger the scan, I noticed the ports always show up as filtered.

I know that all 1,000 ports showing up as filtered generally means there's a firewall rule somewhere that's causing packets to drop, but I can't figure out where it is.

Our infrastructure setup is:

- GCP/GKE for Kubernetes on GCP
- Dockerized containers deployed and managed by Kube
- Istio service mesh

Here's what I've tried (didn't work):

- Updated the `egress` firewall rule in GCP to allow everything (all ports, protocols) on all my instances
- Added NAT gateway to the network to make sure it could access external things
- Made sure Istio had all outbound enabled (no restrictive egress rules)

Is there anything I can do to help further debug this or figure out where the firewall rules might be applied?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you using GCP Comute Engine or Google Kubernetes Engine? What version of Kubernetes are you using? This Istio service mesh is deployed or did you use Istio addon on GKE?

Comment: Google Kubernetes Engine, 1.15.9-gke.24, I deployed istio via istioctl (not the addon on GKE).

Comment: I strongly suspect this has to do with Istio, though I doubt your outbound traffic is being filtered. Can you spin up a test cluster without istio and test?

Comment: @PatrickW I spun up another cluster without istio and ran nmap from that pod and it worked, so you're right that this is an istio issue. I tried on istio version 1.4.3, 1.5.x, and now 1.6.0 and all have the same problem. Maybe has to do with the sidecar. I'll continue debugging...

Comment: AFAIK, this is working as intended. Istio uses security policies to prevent things like that as port scanning could be considered as a potential threat. I'm not even sure if its possible with istio, as it has Zero trust policy by design and port scanning kind of needs access to every used port.

Comment: What are You trying to achieve by scanning the ports? Istio offers its own [observability](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/observability/) features.

Comment: @PiotrMalec I should clarify that saying "this is an istio" issue is the wrong phrasing; I realize it's working as intended! Just meant that was where my problem was. I have a tool that's scanning ports of user websites, and it's deployed in this setup. I'll dig into it and report back when I fix it.

Comment: Although if anyone has any ideas on how to adjust the envoy policies to allow egress port scanning... would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I ended up solving this:

I made use of the `traffic.sidecar.istio.io/includeOutboundIPRanges` annotation on my pod. I set that to be the CIDR of the service mesh.

Doing that made it so any requests going out of that pod *to* something within my mesh was sent through Envoy. Anything else was ignored by Envoy (allowing the `nmap` requests to scan properly instead of being filtered).

There are probably a number of other ways to get this to work given how much customization there seems to available in Istio, but this satisfied my requirements.